# How can I add a specific substring to tokenize on in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy

I am using `spaCy` to tokenize a string, and the string is likely to contain a specific substring.  If the substring is present, I would like `spaCy` to treat the substring as a token, regardless of any other rules it has.  I would like to keep all other rules intact.  Is this possible?

To provide a concrete example, suppose the substring of interest is `'banana'`; I want `'I like bananabread.'` to be tokenized as `['I', 'like', 'banana', 'bread', '.']`.

Where do I go from here (keeping in mind that I would like to keep the rest of the tokenizer rules intact)?  I have tried adding `'banana'` to the prefixes, suffixes, and infixes, with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the string as a prefix, suffix, and infix should work, but depending on which version of spacy you're using, you may have run into a caching bug while testing. This bug is fixed in v2.2+.

With spacy v2.3.2:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = "I like bananabread."
assert [t.text for t in nlp(text)] == ['I', 'like', 'bananabread', '.']

prefixes = ("banana",) + nlp.Defaults.prefixes
suffixes = ("banana",) + nlp.Defaults.suffixes
infixes = ("banana",) + nlp.Defaults.infixes

prefix_regex = spacy.util.compile_prefix_regex(prefixes)
suffix_regex = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)
infix_regex = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)

nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search = prefix_regex.search
nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search = suffix_regex.search
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_regex.finditer

assert [t.text for t in nlp(text)]  == ['I', 'like', 'banana', 'bread', '.']
```

(In v2.1 or earlier, the tokenizer customization still works on a newly loaded `nlp`, but if you've already processed some texts with the `nlp` pipeline and then modify the settings, the bug was that it would use the stored tokenization from the cache rather than the new settings.)

Comment: I feel confused—this is exactly what I attempted to do yesterday, and I am having trouble finding any difference between your code and mine.  Most likely, I just evaluated code in the wrong order in my script, and then assumed that these utility functions didn't do what I thought they did.  I am using spaCy 2.3.2 also.

Comment: If it's not the caching problem, another thing to be aware of is that the order of the affixes matters, since it will use the first match if finds. So if your substring includes another shorter affix, that one could be found first and the tokenizer would break up the substring. You would usually want to have the longest affixes first in the list. You can use `nlp.tokenizer.explain(text)` to debug what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Tokenization occurs at the beginning of the spaCy pipeline, so you should preprocess the text first.

I've written a function that uses regular expressions to pad substrings in compound words:

```
import re

text = 'I eat bananas and bananabread at the bookstore.'

def separate_compound_toks(text):
    anti_compound = sorted(['banana', 'store'])
    anti_compound = "|".join(t.lower() for t in anti_compound)
    # pad word from end
    pattern_a = re.compile(r'(?i)({sub})(?=[a-z]{{3,}})'.format(sub=anti_compound))
    text = re.sub(pattern_a, r'\1 ', text)
    # pad word from beginning
    pattern_b = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<![^a-z])({sub})'.format(sub=anti_compound))
    text = re.sub(pattern_b, r' \1', text)
    return text


import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
 
doc = nlp(separate_compound_toks(text))
print([tok.text for tok in doc])
# ['I', 'eat', 'bananas', 'and', 'banana', 'bread', 'at', 'the', 'book', 'store', '.']
```

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer this strategy to that of the answer from @aab?

Comment: @BioBroo Both approaches have their merits, I believe this method is more customizable. Here you can tokenize `bananas` as a single token instead of `['banana', 's']`